# What did the brave shul men die from?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

A plaque in the back of my shul says:

"This plaque is in memory of all the brave men that died during service."

It seems that these men died during the middle of davening or something. What did they die from?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Does it really say that? "In the service" sounds more natural to my ears.

Comment: @danf From my experience it is more likely they died from eating too much chulent and rugelach during the kiddish. After all, the kiddish is still part of the overall services.

Answer (score 13):

Did you notice the plaque next to it that reads "no talking during services"? 
The one you mention is a warning sign.

Answer (score 6):

Sadly, there was a shark in the mikvah.

Answer (score 1):

This would appear to be a reference to the heroes of Matzada. I remember seeing a reference to the tefillin found in Matzadah. It appears that they found people with only the shel yad and people with both the shel rosh and the shel yad. They also saw a difference in the way the people with only the shel yad were. Some seemed to have been putting away the tefillin and others taking them out. The suggestion was made that the earliest minyon had ended, the later minyon was in the middle of davening, the third minyon was about to start, and the final minyon was on guard against attack and therefore had not started yet.